# Prevent certain tags from being escaped with Underscore templates

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, client-side-templating, underscore.js-templating

I'm using Underscore templates and would like to leverage their HTML escaping functionality while allowing some tags to still come through.

Looking over their implementation, though, it appears that it's an all-or-nothing situation: with escaping turned on, all HTML entities are escaped. I can't, for example, escape everything except some "safe" tags, like, say, `<p>` or `<strong>`, etc.

The best way to get around this limitation seems to be overriding Underscore's [`_.escape()` and `_.unescape()`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/a315e9f4473005a8310540b16d565519a9556106/underscore.js#L1191-L1198), but that actually seems like a terrible idea, and not something I want to do. There's got to be a simpler, more direct way, even if it means using another template engine.

Comment: Just `unescape` the part which doesn't need escaping.

Comment: I guess it would help to see some context code as to what you're trying to do. I get the feeling that maybe you're trying to save some string with tag elements to persist the stylistic intention of the author, but don't want to render it unescaped lest some baddies decide to include <script> etc?